# Merging Two Headings Into One

Tags: r

Very simple question.  I am using an excel sheet that has two rows for the column headings; how can I convert these two row headings into one?   Further, these headings don't start at the top of the sheet.

Thus, I have DF1

```
Temp Press  Reagent  Yield A  Conversion etc
degC bar    /g       %        %             
1    2      3        4        5          
6    7      8        9        10
```

and I want,

```
Temp degC Press bar  Reagent /g  Yield A % Conversion etc
1         2          3           4         5          
6         7          8           9        10
```

Using colnames(DF1) returns the upper names, but getting the second line to merge with the upper one keeps eluding me.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, and take a look at `merge`.

Comment: It's difficult (for me) to make the example reproducible because I'm copying from the excel sheet to the clipboard and getting the data into R via read.table.

Comment: Dump the data to a `.csv` file from Excel, and upload the files.

Comment: I've used that to get all of the scraps of data together but excel's merge and centre doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data, modified to quote text fields that contain the separator (get whatever tool you used to generate the file to quote text fields for you!)

```
txt <- "Temp Press  Reagent  'Yield A'  'Conversion etc'
degC bar    /g       %        %             
1    2      3        4        5          
6    7      8        9        10
"
```

this snippet of code below reads the file in two steps

1. First we read the data, so `skip = 2` means skip the first 2 lines
2. Next we read the data again but only the first two line, this output is then further processed by `sapply()` where we `paste(x, collapse = " ")` the strings in the columns of the `labs` data frame. These are assigned to the `names` of `dat`

Here is the code:

```
dat <- read.table(text = txt, skip = 2)
labs <- read.table(text = txt, nrows = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(dat) <- sapply(labs, paste, collapse = " ")

dat
names(dat)
```

The code, when runs produces:

```
> dat <- read.table(text = txt, skip = 2)
> labs <- read.table(text = txt, nrows = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> names(dat) <- sapply(labs, paste, collapse = " ")
> 
> dat
  Temp degC Press bar Reagent /g Yield A % Conversion etc %
1         1         2          3         4                5
2         6         7          8         9               10
> names(dat)
[1] "Temp degC"        "Press bar"        "Reagent /g"      
[4] "Yield A %"        "Conversion etc %"
```

In your case, you'll want to modify the `read.table()` calls to point at the file on your file system, so use `file = "foo.txt"` in place of `text = txt` in the code chunk, where `"foo.txt"` is the name of your file.

Also, if these headings don't start at the top of the file, then increase `skip` to `2+n` where `n` is the number of lines **before** the two header rows. You'll also need to add `skip = n` to the second `read.table()` call which generates `labs`, where `n` is again the number of lines before the header lines.

Comment: @Arun I had missed the point about the headers not being at the top of the file. Just increase `skip` by an appropriate number of lines. Added to the Answer.

Comment: "get whatever tool you used to generate the file to quote text fields for you!" I used read.table(file="clipboard", header = TRUE, sep = "\t") to give me my table.  I'm scratching my head as to how I can covert this to a text string.  I've just tried, singleString <- paste(readLines("clipboard"), sep = "\t", collapse=" ") but this doesn't take into account the line breaks.  I think it is only giving me a small amount of the whole file, though??

Comment: Then don't use the clipboard. How about you copy/paste it to a new Excel sheet with only that data in it. Then export the sheet as a CSV and make sure Excel quotes the text strings (the headers), otherwise, if you use a space as the separator, how can R tell the difference between a space in a header for a single cell and a space used to separate headers for adjacent cells? More seriously, copy/paste is **not** reproducible anything; eradicate that from your workflow and you'll find things are somewhat easier.

Comment: You wont believe this but ... trying to find out how to quote in excel I stumbled across the concatentate function, http://www.wikihow.com/Concatenate-Text-in-Microsoft-Excel.  I used this to collapse the two headers into one in excel, exported as csv and imported this into R.  (Thanks for the tip about getting away from pasting from the clipboard).

Answer (score 2):

This should work. You only need set stringsAsFactors=FALSE when reading data.

```
data <- structure(list(Temp = c("degC", "1", "6"), Press = c("bar", "2", 
"7"), Reagent = c("/g", "3", "8"), Yield.A = c("%", "4", "9"), 
    Conversion = c("%", "5", "10")), .Names = c("Temp", "Press", 
"Reagent", "Yield.A", "Conversion"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)) # Your data

colnames(data) <-paste(colnames(dados),dados[1,]) # Set new names
data <- data[-1,] # Remove first line

data <- data.frame(apply(data,2,as.real)) # Correct the classes (works only if all collums are numbers)
```

Comment: I think they are always 1 and 2 from data, but not from excel sheet... using skip=NumbersOfLinesToSkip should work

Answer (score 2):

Just load your file with `read.table(file, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = F)` arguments. Then, you can `grep` to find the position this happens.

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(sample(10), "Temp", "degC"), 
                 V2=c(sample(10), "Press", "bar"), 
                 V3 = c(sample(10), "Reagent", "/g"), 
                 V4 = c(sample(10), "Yield_A", "%"), 
                 V5 = c(sample(10), "Conversion", "%"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
idx <- unique(c(grep("Temp", df$V1), grep("degC", df$V1)))
df2 <- df[-(idx), ]
names(df2) <- sapply(df[idx, ], function(x) paste(x, collapse=" "))
```

Here, if you want, you can then convert all the columns to numeric as follows:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df2, as.numeric))
```

Comment: Your `df` doesn't look like the OPs data - you have the header split with data in between. I read the Q to indicate the two header lines were contiguous just not at the top of the file.

Comment: Well, who knows? But their example data show the header as two contiguous lines. This also fits with the modus operandi of Excel users, with tables arranged away from the top of the sheet.